# How do I stream video from laptop's camera using kinesis video stream producer(WebRTC)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I am using AWS kinesis video streams to stream live video and perform facial recognition on image feed. I need assistance in understanding some basic concepts regarding it:-
1) If I want to use WerRTC for live streaming how will I do that?
2) In kinesis video streams there is a channel and a stream(when using webRTC it's connecting to a channel, how do I connect it to a video stream?)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps and use Kinesis Video Producer GStreamer sample to do live streaming from your laptop camera: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp#build-and-install-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-and-sample-applications

(1) Currently KVS WebRTC is just for realtime peer-to-peer streaming, it is not applicable for facial recognition now. 
(2) If you want both realtime peer-to-peer playback and also cloud storage, you will need to do the first one with KVS WebRTC and do the latter one with KVS producer. A reference of how to do both at the same time: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-c/issues/161#issuecomment-579621542

Answer (score -1):

Regarding (1), AWS provide instructions of how to ingest the stream via WebRTC [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams-webrtc-dg/latest/devguide/webrtc-ingestion.html).

Regarding (2), to connect the channel to the stream stream, you can follow the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams-webrtc-dg/latest/devguide/configure-ingestion.html).

You also mentioned facial recognition - whilst this is not directly supported by Amazon Kinesis Video Streams, beside implementing it on your laptop you have a few options - one would be to ingest the video into another AWS service like [AWS Rekognition](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/improve-your-customer-service-using-amazon-kinesis-video-streams-and-amazon-rekognition-video/) or e.g. using an AXIS camera [with facial recognition](https://www.sdmmag.com/articles/98185-safr-facial-recognition-now-runs-on-the-axis-camera-application-platform) and then using an out-of-the-box service like [KVstreamer](https://kvstreamer.scoville.jp/) to directly send the video to AWS Kinesis Video Streams.

Comment: 1) Link-only answers are not valid answers; 2) this question is from four years ago and is off-topic. Please don't answer off-topic questions.